# Pydev and Django: Shell not finding certain modules?

Tags: django, pydev, django-shell

I am developing a Django project with PyDev in Eclipse. For a while, PyDev's Django Shell worked great. Now, it doesn't:

```
>>> import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
C:\Python26\python.exe 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> 
>>> from django.core import management;import mysite.settings as settings;management.setup_environ(settings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysite.settings
>>>
```

The dev server runs just fine. What could I be doing wrong?

The models module is also conspicuously absent:

```
>>> import mysite.myapp.models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysite.myapp.models
```

On the normal command line, outside of PyDev, the shell works fine.

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a simple path issue. What's the output of this:

```
import sys; print sys.path
```

I don't know anything about PyDev, but there's probably a setting somewhere to add paths to the PYTHONPATH setting. If not, you can do it directly in the shell:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/directory/containing/mysite/')
```

Comment: Great answer. Pydev does not add the .bin folder while auto config. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to this a while ago while moving my project from Django 1.3 and having the settings.py file at the root of my source and then moving it down into the application.

For example what happened was that I had the following:

rootOfSource/
    - settings.py
    - myapp

and I changed it to be:

rootOfSource/
    - myapp
    - myapp/settings.py

and I also changed my settings file to be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

However when I debugged into the os.eviron I found that the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was not as expected, I then changed my manage.py to be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    os.environ.__setitem__("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Which then allowed me to run from PyDev.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by going to the project properties -> PyDev Django and setting the Django settings module.
[image]